# How to create working Powershell task to stop process hung Firefox process?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I tried to script code to stop hung Firefox process, I want the script to stop all Firefox browser processes periodically.

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At 14:20
$options = New-ScheduledJobOption -WakeToRun 
Register-ScheduledJob -Name StopFirefox -ScriptBlock {Stop-Process -Name "Firefox" -Force} -Trigger $trigger -ScheduledJobOption $options
```

But I get Task Scheduled answer that `2147942402` which translates to "File not Found" for both:

`{Stop-Process -Name "Firefox" -Force}` and `{Get-Process -Name "Firefox" | Stop-Process}`

Comment: I wanted to make questions specific since powerShell has two modules to automate Task Schedule Tasks. PSScheduledJob is designated for Powershell Scripts.

Comment: are you sure that during that time there is a FireFox process running

Comment: Yes I do. I also activated Firefox on purpose. Does the code scheduled on Task Schedule works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the permission to the job to by adding a user under which the Job runs and who can stop your process, because the process was launched unter a certain user.

If I you add `-Credential (Get-Credential)` to the `Register-ScheduledJob` Cmdlet then you should be prompted once for entering your credentials and after that your code should run fine and stop your Firefox process.

Comment: I still get error with return code 2147942401. Powershell cmd shows:
[+CategoryInfo : SeurityError : (:) [], PSSecurityException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId       : UnauthorizedAccess]
I use user without with password to login but without settings. Other automated files "run wheather user logged or not in".

Comment: I tested your code with the parameter as I said and it works on my Windows 10 1709 (16299.371) and PowerShell Version 5.1.16299.251. From which output do you get the return code? Did you run it in PowerShell window with administrative rights?

Comment: Can you see the configured job in the Windows "Task Scheduler" under "Microsoft/Windows/PowerShell/ScheduledJobs"?

Comment: I get return code from Task Schedule History Event. I do not specify Powershell window to run as administrator. How to write code? I used "Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs" with .ps1 file it works, how to run with the module? The job is configured in Windows/Powershell. I still get error to run script Task Start, Failed 2147942402.

Comment: Try to start your PowerShell Session as an administrator via the context menue of powershell. exe or your link in your taskbar. Choose "run as Administrator". Your job scriptblock can stay like in your original question. And add the code I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I wrote the code same way. It still does not work, I think this is Windows10 configuration settings conflict situation with login access. I will Transcribe error to text file data and try to solve this way in Microsoft forums.

Comment: The useful link how to run Task Schedule wheathe user is logged or not is [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc722152(v=ws.11))